# Increment last letter of a string

Tags: java, string

Here's where I wish Java's String class had a replaceLast method, bu it doesn't and I'm getting the wrong results with my code.

I'm writing a program that searches a data structure for any items that match a string prefix.  However, since I'm using an Iterator, the last item returned by the iter.next() call doesn't match the pattern, so I want to change the search string so that the last character of the query is increased by one letter.  My testing code is returning [C@b82368 with this code and `An` as titleSearch:

```
public String changeLastCharacter(String titleSearch) {
    char[] temp= titleSearch.toCharArray();

    char lastLetter= temp[temp.length-1];
    lastLetter++;
    temp[temp.length-1]= lastLetter;

    String newTitleSearch= temp.toString();
    return newTitleSearch;
}
```

First, what is the cause of the output from this code?
Second, is there a better way to execute my solution?

Comment: Are you saying you want to make the last letter in the string the next letter alphabetically? i.e. `aa` becomes `ab`?

Comment: Thats what I was looking for.  I mixed up the toString method with creating a new String, since I thought the Char class had a toString method that returned a string of the entire array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want:

```
newTitleSearch = new String(temp);
```

The `toString` method is not overridden for arrays; it's the usual `Object.toString`, intended for debugging.  The above actually creates a string of the characters.  An alternative is:

```
int len = titleSearch.length();
String allButLast = titleSearch.substring(0, len - 1);
newTitleSearch = allButLast + new Character(titleSearch.charAt(len - 1) + 1);
```

Comment: I figured it was something like this.  I was following an example and mixed up the last line of code.  Time for me to call it a day now.

Comment: Nit-pick: *"The character array toString method is similar to the default ..."*.  Actually, it >>is<< the default; i.e. `Object.toString()`.

Comment: @Stephen, thanks, I forgot the array specifier ("[C") was just the class name.

Comment: I tried this code and it didn't work.  I think that charAt() + 1 was converted to an int and then the int was added to allButLast as a string.

Comment: @Eyal, thanks.  I think it should be fixed now.  Note though that's just the alternative implementation.  The first one is simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you see unexpected output like `....@<hex-digits>`, the chances are that you are accidentally using `toString()` on some object whose class inherits the default implementation from `Object`.

The default `toString()` method returns a String whose value consists of the type name for the object combined with the object's "identity hash code" as hex digits.  In your case the `[C` part is the type name for a `char[]` object.  The '[' means "array of" and the 'C' means the `char` primitive type.

The rules for forming the type names used in the default `toString()` method are fully documented in the javadocs for [`java.lang.Class.getName()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName%28%29).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I don't use toString all that much, so was unfamiliar with the unexpected output.  You really do learn something new every day.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is `temp.toString()`.  Try `String newTitleSearch = new String(temp);` instead.

I figured this out by `System.out.println(temp[0]+","+temp[1]);` after temp[1] add been assigned to the incremented value.  You could do this even easier by using your IDE's debugger.

Since the array was being assigned properly, the problem had to be in the `toString()`.