# What data structure can I use to hold elements of an array if the array elements start with a string without looping through the initial array

Tags: java, data-structures

I am trying to implement an autocomplete method that receives an input string and searches through a given array of words for the words that have the input string as the prefix of the words in the array.

I have successfully implemented this by looping through the array of words and returning all the elements with the prefix of given input string. However, I believe that there should be an optimal way of doing this as I realized that I am looping through all elements of the array after sorting the elements.

I want to select only elements in the array that begin with the first letter of the given string and then search that sub-array for the words that have the string as their prefix. This will cut the processing time considerably and provide an optimal solution.

What data structure can I use that will not require me to loop through the entire given array, or dictionary key (I tried implementing this using a map), but only chose the sub-array containing elements close to the solution?

PS: I also played with ArrayUtils.subArray() of Apache Commons but could not retrieve the sub-array. Any ideas on how to implement this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Comment: That's absolutely Trie. Check [Trie Applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie#Applications).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a TreeSet.   Once populated, given a String prefix you could get all matching words by

```
Set<String> findWords(String prefix) {
    // copied from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002021/increment-last-letter-of-a-string
    int len = prefix.length();
    String allButLast = prefix.substring(0, len - 1);
    String endPrefix = allButLast + new Character(prefix.charAt(len - 1) + 1);

    return treeSet.subSet(prefix, endPrefix); 
}
```

Comment: each string of length n would require O(n^2) space for storing

Comment: @mangusta Why do you think that? As far as I'm aware the space complexity of a TreeSet is O(n).

Comment: @Mangusta I'd be interested in the source for that.  My understanding is TreeSet (and TreeMap) takes 40 bytes per node, plus the values (eg http://java-performance.info/memory-consumption-of-java-data-types-2/ )

Comment: ah I confused it with hashset. treeset indeed looks up the range within linear time. Still the space is worse than trie, because all the keys are stored as is. ( aba abc abd versus ab prefix and three branches for a c d )

Comment: and the range search will check the prefix of every key on tree traversal while in trie the prefix is checked only once and then all children are inspected. so basically the time complexity for treeset-based range search is O (n * length (prefix)) versus O (length (prefix) + number of qualifying strings) in trie